# After Effects Javascript: Script-only countdown timer

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

Adobe After Effects supports Javascript and provides a hany method of `time`.

It provides a floating point number of current time of the composition and can be used in numerous ways.

```
60 - time // Starts the countdown timer from 60.
```

**I'm trying to create countdown timer that starts from a random number and resets to 59 once it hits 0.**

There are few ways to achieve it but I need a `expressions-only` solution as I want multiple repetitions and want to avoid multiple comps and layers.

```
seedRandom(45, timeless=true) // Random shouldn't generate at every frame.

r = random(1, 59)
sec = r - time 

if (sec < 0) {
  sec = 60 - (time%60);
}

Math.floor(sec);
```

**Problem:**

The above code works but repeats from the `random number` for the first `two iterations` rather than start from first time only.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there some sort of online IDE were we can try this? Guess that you can add the difference between last loop and current loop to `sec`.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any online IDE. If not completely rewriting the logic, one needs to focus on dividing a growing number to limit it from 60 to 0

Comment: You're confusing script and expressions. What you've posted is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `if` statement, modulus `%` will do the job, much more simply.

Since you need to repeat every 60 seconds after the first time you can use `time % 60`.

Since you want it to count down use `60 - (time % 60)` which gives us a sawtooth starting at 59 and going down to 0, back up to 59, etc.

So now we need to offset it by a random amount. If we have a random number that is >= 0 and < 60 we can add that to time, and the first loop will start at a number between 0 and 59.

TL;DR

```
seedRandom(45, timeless=true);
Math.floor( 60 - ((time +  random(0, 59)) % 60));
```